Pasando parametros a una vista mysql o phpMyadmin desde un controlador laravel
¿Como puedo enviar los parametros desde un controlador laravel a una vista phpMyAdmin que necesita los parametros: date_inicial_a, date_final_a, date_inicial_b, date_final_b ?
Ni siquiera puedo crear la vista en phpMyAdmin, me manda el error: "#1351 - View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter"
CREATE VIEW balanza_comprobacion AS 

WITH RECURSIVE balanza1 AS (
    SELECT a.id as account_id, a.id as balance_account_id 
    FROM accounts AS a 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT a.cfather AS account_id, b1.balance_account_id 
    FROM balanza1 as b1 
    INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.id = b1.account_id 
    WHERE a.cfather IS NOT NULL
), 
movimientos_ene_feb AS (
    SELECT 
        a.account_id, 
        SUM(pd.cargo) AS cargos_ene_feb, 
        SUM(pd.abono) AS abonos_ene_feb, 
        SUM(pd.cargo) - SUM(pd.abono) AS saldo_inicial
    FROM balanza1 AS a 
    INNER JOIN policy_details AS pd 
        ON pd.account_id = a.balance_account_id 
    /* Estos parametros necesito envialos desde laravel: @date_inicial_a, @date_final_a*/
    WHERE pd.fecha_pol >= @date_inicial_a AND pd.fecha_pol <= @date_final_a 
    GROUP BY a.account_id
), 
movimientos_mar AS (
    SELECT 
        a.account_id, 
        SUM(pd.cargo) AS cargos_marzo, 
        SUM(pd.abono) AS abonos_marzo
    FROM balanza1 AS a 
    INNER JOIN policy_details AS pd 
        ON pd.account_id = a.balance_account_id 
    /* Estos parametros necesito enviarlos desde laravel: @date_inicial_b, @date_final_b*/
    WHERE pd.fecha_pol >= @date_inicial_b AND pd.fecha_pol <= @date_final_b 
    GROUP BY a.account_id
)
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.nombre, 
    COALESCE(ene_feb.saldo_inicial, 0) AS saldo_inicial,
    COALESCE(mar.cargos_marzo, 0) AS cargos_marzo,
    COALESCE(mar.abonos_marzo, 0) AS abonos_marzo,
    COALESCE(ene_feb.saldo_inicial, 0) + COALESCE(mar.cargos_marzo, 0) - COALESCE(mar.abonos_marzo, 0) AS saldo_final_marzo
FROM accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN movimientos_ene_feb AS ene_feb ON a.id = ene_feb.account_id
LEFT JOIN movimientos_mar AS mar ON a.id = mar.account_id
ORDER BY a.id;

Quitando los parametros de la consulta, si me permite crear la vista y desde el controlador de laravel la llamo de la siguiente manera:
$balanza =  DB::table('balanza_comprobacion')->get();

Pero a la consulta de la vista anterior, necesito pasarle los parametros dinamicos:
date_inicial_a, date_final_a, date_inicial_b, date_final_b.
Y eso es lo que no puedo hacer: pasarle los parametros desde el controlador laravel a la vista creada en phpMyAdmin.
La vista anterior la hice en phpMyAdmin ya que tengo entendido que eloquent o Query Builder no son capaces de ejecutar consultas CTE recursivas.
Dejo el codigo para otra posible consulta directamente desde eloquent o Query Builder sin la necesidad de una vista CTE recursiva en phpMyadmin:
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `cfather` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nature_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL);


   CREATE TABLE `policy_details` (
  `policy_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `account_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `concepto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cargo` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `abono` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_pol` date NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `cfather`, `nombre`, `nature_id`) VALUES
(102000000, NULL, 'Bancos', 'D'),
(102001000, 102000000, 'bancos nacionales', 'D'),
(102001001, 102001000, 'Banamex', 'D'),
(102001002, 102001000, 'Bancomer', 'D'),
(102002000, 102000000, 'Bancos extranjeros', 'D'),
(102002001, 102002000, 'Citibank', 'D'),
(102002002, 102002000, 'J P Morgan', 'D'),
(107000000, NULL, 'Deudores diversos', 'D'),
(107001000, 107000000, 'Funcionarios y empleados', 'D'),
(107005000, 107000000, 'Otros deudores diversos', 'D'),
(201000000, NULL, 'Proveedores', 'H'),
(201001000, 201000000, 'Proveedores nacionales', 'H'),
(201002000, 201000000, 'Proveedores extranjeros', 'H'),
(205000000, NULL, 'Acreedores diversos cp', 'H'),
(205001000, 205000000, 'Acreedores diversos cp nal', 'H'),
(205002000, 205000000, 'Acreedores diversos cp ext', 'H'),
(600000000, NULL, 'Gastos', 'D'),
(602000000, 600000000, 'Gastos de venta', 'D'),
(602050000, 602000000, 'Telefono e internet', 'D'),
(602052000, 602000000, 'Energia electrica', 'D'),
(603000000, 600000000, 'Gastos de administración', 'D'),
(603050000, 603000000, 'Telefono e internet', 'D'),
(603052000, 603000000, 'Energia electrica', 'D');

INSERT INTO `policy_details` (`policy_id`, `account_id`, `concepto`, `cargo`, `abono`, `fecha_pol`) VALUES
(1, 102001001, 'Prestamo recibido', 400.00, 0.00, '2024-01-01'),
(1, 205001000, 'Prestamo recibido', 0.00, 750.00, '2024-01-01'),
(1, 102001002, 'Prestamo recibido', 100.00, 0.00, '2024-01-01'),
(1, 102002001, 'Prestamo recibido', 200.00, 0.00, '2024-01-01'),
(1, 102002002, 'Prestamo recibido', 50.00, 0.00, '2024-01-01'),
(2, 107001000, 'Prestamo a empleado', 20.00, 0.00, '2024-02-07'),
(2, 102001001, 'Prestamo a empleado', 0.00, 20.00, '2024-02-07'),
(3, 603050000, 'Pago telefono', 10.00, 0.00, '2024-03-12'),
(3, 102001002, 'Pago telefono', 0.00, 10.00, '2024-03-12');


El error te lo está dejando en claro "#1351 - View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter"  las vistas no pueden contener variables.  A lo mejor podrías crear un procedimiento almacenado que devolviera lo que buscas. Mira esta respuesta para ver cómo podrías invocarlo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69706373/how-to-execute-mysql-stored-procedure-from-laravel-8-0-with-any-parameters
